# What's a simple way of setting up user rate throttling (for end user and myself)(using AWS Cognito?) for Python based coding

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am putting together a small service with Amazon's API Gateway and Lambda services. This service will be free to users but I'd like to try and limit users from making too many requests. Ideally, I'd like to do some sort of IP based throttling as well, but my impression is that IP based throttling is uncommon and potentially problematic.

AWS Cognito seems like it can be used with the API Gateway for this task, but it is not clear to me if there is any easy way for me to get it up and running (without any web hosting) and for users to use it (with something like Python's requests package).

Ultimately, I'd like something that is relatively easy, like the following:

```py
r=requests.get(my_api_url,params=params,auth=(user_cognito_name, user_cognito_password))
```

or more likely something like:

```py
user_jwt_token = <some_magic> #Not sure how to implement this
r=requests.get(my_api_url,params=params,auth=user_jwt_token)
```

From what I've seen, the Python libraries to implement Cognito access seem quite complicated ...

- https://github.com/capless/warrant
- https://github.com/pvizeli/pycognito

Then there is also the issue of getting the tokens. This post describes how to setup token maintenance using a bunch of AWS lambda functions:

https://medium.com/@houzier.saurav/aws-cognito-with-python-6a2867dd02c6

The advantage of this approach, I presume, is that you avoid setting up a server, which I would like to do as well. However, it seems really complicated.

Ideally I'd like an AWS service like "AWS Cognito Manager" or "AWS Cognito Helper" in which you specify some basic AWS cognito information then you get a specific URL. Anyone can then go to that URL to get a token. I'm not sure what maintenance is needed with tokens but ideally that same website -- managed by AWS or some company that I pay -- would also handle maintenance issues, if any. Alternatively, simple python code for maintenance would also be fine. What I'm trying to avoid is building my own website or trying to piece together a ton of Lambda calls or setting up an EC2 instance specifically to handle logins.

```py
#Example of desired renewal code
renewed_token = magic_function(base_token,user_name,user_password)
```

Note, after all of this, my entire approach may be wrong. Perhaps I don't really need AWS Cognito or I'm just thinking about the problem in the wrong way.

Comment: Seems what you want is Cognito User Pool Host UI https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-integration.html

Comment: I'll have to take a closer look at that option. It's not clear to me where a user goes for login, perhaps that is obvious if I fill out the forms. I'm still not clear as to what the one to two liner in Python would be for authentication once the user has a token.

Comment: With host UI, you will get a hosted domain URL for authentication. It needs a callback URL which is your apps URL. You will see some callback response once login succeed/failed such as grand code or jwt token. There you go can parse the token to get the user info